# OpenMP task dependencies: DAG scheduling

Tags: openmp

OpenMP specification says: "List items used in depend clauses of the same task or sibling tasks must indicate identical storage or disjoint storage." (OpenMP 4.0 spec, page 117, line 14-15).

I am not sure if I have understood the “disjoint” description from the standard correctly. If I am using array to specify the dependencies, for example:

```
int x[10];     //this is the data array which will be updated by various tasks (with dependencies)
int *tmp;      //max 3 dependencies, known at task creation time

#pragma omp parallel 
{ 
   #pragma omp single nowait
   {
      for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
          tmp = get_dependencies(i)         //for i=0 => tmp[0]=1, tmp[1]=3, tmp[2]=5  (the values 1,3,5 are actual dependencies)
                                            //for i=1 => tmp[0]=2, tmp[1]=3, tmp[2]=7
                                            //for i=2 => tmp[0]=0, tmp[1]=8, tmp[2]=9

          #pragma  omp task depend (inout:tmp[0], inout:tmp[1], inout:tmp[2] )       
          {
                        //task is going to updated values at x[ tmp[0] ],  x[ tmp[1] ],  x[ tmp[2] ]
          } 

      }
   }
}
```

So I want task1 depend on the task0 (because x[tmp[1]] i.e. x[3] will be updated by task0 which will be consumed by task1) and task2 to be independent.

OR do I need to use something like?

```
 #pragma  omp task depend (inout:x[tmp[0]], inout:x[tmp[1]].....
```

OR

```
int *p = &x[tmp[0]];
int *q = &x[tmp[1]];
int *r = &x[tmp[2]];

 #pragma  omp task depend (inout:p[0], inout:q[0].....
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I tried this in our application and following implementation works fine:

```
  #pragma  omp task depend (inout:x[tmp[0]], inout:x[tmp[1]].....
```

I assume "disjoint storage" storage means use of "x" used to specify the task dependencies (one can not use pointers to specify dependencies as discussed in openmp forum (see first response) [here](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1879)).